# Nginx - password protect single directory

Tags: php, nginx, basic-authentication

No matter what I try, I cannot seem to get Nginx to password-protect a subdirectory.

I want the `admin` directory and its contents to be password-protected, but none of the configurations I've tried make the basic auth popup appear.

```
/
  admin/
    index.php
    file.zip
  index.php
```

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

#### `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

```
server {
    listen          80 default_server;
    server_name     subdomain.example.com;

    root            /srv/www/example.com/subdomain/http;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files               $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        include                 fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /admin {
        auth_basic              "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass        unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index       index.php;
            include             fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried various permutations including `location ^~ /admin` and `location ^~ admin/index.php` but nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Comment: My bad, it was only because SO suggested it.